# Partitionkey is ignored in CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azureservicebus

I have a flow where I send a json document to the ServiceBus and a function listens to the topic and creates a document in my CosmosDB.

The CosmosDB has the partitionkey "targetid"
[image: CosmosDB settings]

When I provide the document from the Function

[image: Function]

The document is inserted and I can pull it again from c# using CreateDocumentQuery but I cant see the document in the portal and no logical partitions has been created based on the value in the targetid property.

If I create a document directly from the portal and pulls it with CreateDocumentQuery in my application then the document also has a completely different format than the documents that has been created from the application itself through ServiceBus and Functions.

Comment: Is this a Mongo API account?

Comment: Hi @MatiasQuaranta. Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosmos DB Change Feed (what the Cosmos DB Trigger reads) is not available on Mongo DB API accounts at this point. Change Feed is a feature of Cosmos DB and thus, surfaced on the Core / SQL API and, at this point, not available for Mongo DB API accounts.

You can verify the compatibility matrix on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#supported-apis-and-client-sdks).

[image: Change Feed compatibility chart]

As a side note, the fact that you are also using `CreateDocumentQuery` means that you are using the Core/SQL SDK. It would make sense for you to use a Core/SQL API account instead if you are not going to use the Mongo DB drivers or clients.

Comment: you were right. The api was not corresponding. Thanks for pointing that out. I have now switched to the correct API (SQL) and it looks good now. Thanks!